# Laravel eloquent updateOrCreate not inserting large arrays (more than 3000 rows)

Tags: php, laravel, oracle, insert

I am trying to load a large amount of information into a database in one column.
When I load an array of more than 3000 keys, I don't get a row in the DB, it's not even created. If there is less data, then everything is fine.

*DB config :
DB = Oracle 16;
column inserted type = CLOB; memory = unlimit*;

**Controller.php**

```
$ModelData>addData(id, $result_array);
```

**ModelData**

```
    $result_array = collect($result_array);
    $array_collect = collect();
    foreach ($result_array as $item){
        $array_collect ->push($item);
    }
    $this->updateOrCreate(['id_dataset' => $id,], ['data' => $array_collect->toJson()]);
```

maybe create a new row first, and then do an update

Comment: What happens if you run the same query directly on oracle without going through laravel?

Comment: Do it using chunk, chunk will break your big data into small chunks.

Comment: @RajenTrivedi There's only one record being updated. Note the `$array_collect->toJson()`

Comment: @RajenTrivedi with Chunk 

$result_array = collect($result_array );
        $part_data = $result_array ->chunk(400);
        foreach ($part_data as $part){
            $this->updateOrCreate(['id_dataset' => $id,]
                , [
                    'processed_data' => collect($part)->values()->toJson(),
                ]);
        }

Comment: @KevinY Yes, I updated one column

Comment: @KevinY I load in DB all keys, inserted-successed (